# Bash: Regex match betwen first occurrence of characters

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, sed

Input:

```
p45-322-16.jpg
```

Desired output:

```
p45
```

I'm trying to make a bash script with grep or awk or sed or something that could run on a bash shell.

Currently I'm stuck with this:

```
echo "p45-322-16.jpg" | sed 's/\(.*\)-.*/\1/'
```

Output:

```
p45-322
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cut` command: `echo "p45-322-16.jpg" | cut -d"-" -f1`

Answer (score 2):

You need to limit what you will accept. Right now, you are accepting too much by using `.`, and the greedy-by-default nature of regexes is consuming too many characters.

Try either limiting the accepted characters to digits only, or specifically excluding the dash:

```
\([0-9]*\).*

\([^-]*\).*
```

Comment: another option would be to let your regex start at the dash: `s/-.*//`

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "p45-322-16.jpg" | sed 's/\([^-]*\).*/\1/'
```

The `.*` part of your regex is greedy, so it reads as far as possible so that the regex still matches.  This means it claims everything up to the last `-`.

Use `[^-]*` to match everything until a `-`.

Comment: Thanks, great explanation!